# Windows Firewall with Advanced Security Block certain IP's on port 21

Tags: windows-7, firewall, port, filezilla

Windows by default blocks all IP's. I think I made it so that now my advanced firewall is allowing all IP's, but when I add a block rule it doesn't actually block the certain IP. I am using FileZilla to test wether I can get connected to the FileZilla server and it always succeeded no matter what I try it's always or allow all ports or block all.

tl;dr how can I make my firewall so that it allows all IP's and that I can block/ban certain ones. I've seen many guides on Google regarding this subject but all seems to fail.
Running Windows 7 Ultimate N if that matters.

Comment: Did you block the port but allow the program - one rule may over write the other? Further more the order in which you've entered the rules may alter priority - try swapping the order (so open port 21 is above block all and vice versa).